# Typewriter simulator

Tags: windows

I was wondering if there is typewriter software that can simulate the sound and fonts of typing on the PC (Windows), paid or free. Something like Hanx Writer.

Most of my searching on Google has returned with browser based apps which isn what Im looking for.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the terms "typewriter keyboard sound for windows" resulted in many returns. Your search terms are suspect if you were not able to locate a suitable program.

One of the earlier listings is a paid program called [SoundPilot](https://www.colorpilot.com/soundpilot.html) for all versions of Windows from XP onward.

For a free program, Gibson Research offers [ClicKey](https://www.grc.com/freeware/clickey.htm) which is a portable (non-installed) utility:

[image: ClicKey description image]
Image from linked site.